# The equivalent of iSTAT MENUS (system monitoring tool on menu) with Mac to PC?

Tags: windows, performance-monitor

Mac has a tool named iSTAT MENUS as is shown below.

[image]

It's pretty useful in that it shows all the computer status (memory usage/CPU usage/network) real time **on top of the menu**.

Does Windows have similar tools? I know I can use Task Manager, but I want to have it on screen all the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Performance Monitor](http://www.hexagora.com/en_dw_davperf.asp) works with all versions of windows (except 9x and ME) and is a fair equivalent to what you are after.  The built-in task manager utility only shows CPU usage.  There are other utilities you can DL as well but I think this is the best.

Comment: Update for 2018 - Task Manager now shows lots more info, including GPU usage.

Answer (score 7):

Download [RainMeter](http://rainmeter.net).

[image]

It has more features than what istat can do.

Answer (score 3):

[NetSpeedMonitor](http://www.floriangilles.com/software/netspeedmonitor/#c129) is great for monitoring network traffic speeds!

[image]

> NetSpeedMonitor is a lightweight Network Monitoring Toolbar for your Windows Taskbar designed to be used on computers that run Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista or Windows 7. With NetSpeedMonitor you can monitor the current speed (up- and downstream) of your Network Interfaces and the amount of data transferred.

Comment: Note sure why this was voted down, this is a great app.

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: doesn't work on Windows 10

Comment: does work on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same and found:

http://dennisbabkin.com/ctm/

Advantages:

1. runs in the menubar
2. free!
3. relatively attractive